# How to send Cart Items Grid in email?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I am working on custom extension and i need to send cart items with all information in email like selected custom options, how can I do that?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Anshu's solution, consider that from any `$item` you have in the loop you can read item options via `$item->getProductOptions()`;

it will return an array with a `attributes_info` key for configurable items; the value associated to that key holds the applied product configuration;

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I have quite a similar requirement few months back. 
I used below code.

**app/etc/modules/Custom_CartEmail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_CartEmail>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Custom_CartEmail>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Custom/CartEmail/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_CartEmail>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Custom_CartEmail>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <cartEmail>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Custom_CartEmail</module>
                    <frontName>cartEmail</frontName>
                </args>
            </cartEmail>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Custom/CartEmail/controllers/cartEmail.php**

```
<?php
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
$imageHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/image');
?>

<div style="margin:10px 0"> <!-- logo space --> </div>
<table style=" border-collapse:collapse">
    <tr>
        <th style="border: solid 1px #ccc; padding:5px 10px; background:#f4f4f4;"></td>
        <th style="border: solid 1px #ccc; padding:5px 10px; background:#f4f4f4;">Product Name</th>
        <th style="border: solid 1px #ccc; padding:5px 10px; background:#f4f4f4;">Unit Price</th>
        <th style="border: solid 1px #ccc; padding:5px 10px; background:#f4f4f4;">Quantity</th>
        <th style="border: solid 1px #ccc; padding:5px 10px; background:#f4f4f4;">Sub Total</th>
        <?php
        foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
            ?>
        <tr>
            <?php
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $img = $imageHelper->init($item->getProduct(), 'thumbnail');
            $itemName = $item->getName();
            ?>
            <td style="border: solid 1px #ccc; padding:5px 10px "><img src="<?php $img; ?>" alt="<?php echo $itemName; ?>" /></td>
            <td style="border: solid 1px #ccc; padding:5px 10px "><?php echo $itemName; ?></td>
            <td style="border: solid 1px #ccc; padding:5px 10px "><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($item->getPrice()); ?></td>
            <td style="border: solid 1px #ccc; padding:5px 10px "><?php echo $item->getQty(); ?></td>
            <td style="border: solid 1px #ccc; padding:5px 10px "><?php echo $item->getRowTotalInclTax(); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>

<div style=" margin:10px 0; padding:10px 0; text-align:center; border-top:solid 1px #ccc "> &copy; 2003 - 2014, All rights reserved.</div>
```

**app/code/local/Custom/CartEmail/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php

class Custom_CartEmail_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $emailTo = $this->getRequest()->getParam('emailto');
        ob_start();
        include 'cartEmail.php';

        $emailContent = ob_get_contents();

        $fromEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
        $fromName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');
        $toEmail = $emailTo;
        $toName = "Hello! Friend";
        $body = $emailContent;
        $subject = "Cart Products";

        try {
            $mail = new Zend_Mail();
            $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
            $mail->addTo($toEmail, $toName);
            $mail->setSubject($subject);
            $mail->setBodyHtml($body); // here u also use setBodyText options.
            // this is for to set the file format
            $at = new Zend_Mime_Part($body);

            //$at->type = 'application/csv'; // if u have PDF then it would like -> 'application/pdf'
            $at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
            $at->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_8BIT;
            //$at->filename = $file;
            //$mail->addAttachment($at);
            $mail->send();
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Email successfully sent.');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //echo $e->getMassage();
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('There is some error while sending email.');
        }
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
    }

}
```

Try this code and modify according to your requirement and have a better version of it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Anshu, but what about the selected custom options?

Comment: @GauravJain This is the basic code not the full version, you need to modify it according to your requirement. I think you can get the custom options info from the quote object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems(); 
foreach ($items as $item) 
   {
     $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
     foreach($options['attributes_info'] as $curopt)
     {
          // Apply logic on your custom options as per the requirements.
     }
}
```